# pgfplots: Dual axis

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I want to display a dual axis as pictured in Fig.1. But When i write the file .Tex I obtained a different presentation. I want also to display all the numbers between 1-12 in the x-axis. Any help please?

```
\documentclass{article}
% UNITS
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per=slash, load=abbr}
% GRAPHICS
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
 %scale only axis,
 %scaled x ticks=base 10:1,
 xmin=0, xmax=12
}
\begin{axis}[
axis y line*=left,
 ymin=0, ymax=1,
xlabel=x-axis,
ylabel=y-axis 1,
]
\addplot[smooth,mark=x,red]
coordinates{
(12, 0.75)
(11, 0.749)
(10, 0.749)
(9, 0.748)
(8, 0.748)
(7, 0.746)
(6, 0.739)
(5, 0.733)
(4, 0.697)
(3, 0.674)
(2, 0.668)
}; \label{plot_one}
\addlegendentry{plot 1}
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
axis y line*=right,
axis x line=none,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
ylabel=y-axis 2
]
\addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue]
coordinates{
(12, 0.725)
(11, 0.726)
(10, 0.73)
(9, 0.732)
(8, 0.746)
(7,0.754)
(6, 0.832)
(5, 0.828)
(4, 0.912)
(3, 0.96)
(2, 0.992)
}; \addlegendentry{plot 3}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image: Fig. 1]

Comment: add `xtick={0,...,12}` to the first axis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one possibility. Here `grid=both` is added, ymin/ymax are set to differnt values and `y tick label styes` are added and set differently to meet the requirements.

1. For legend in one row, use `legend columns=-1`.
2. For two plots in one legend, use `\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_one} addlegendentry{y axis 1}`

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
% UNITS
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per=slash, load=abbr}
% GRAPHICS
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
 scale only axis,
 %scaled x ticks=base 10:1,
 xmin=0, xmax=12,
}
\begin{axis}[
title=CombinedDemainXYPlotDemo,
xtick={0,...,12},ytick={0.0,0.1,...,1},
%legend style={at={(0.1,-0.2)}, anchor=north west},
axis y line*=left,
ymin=0, ymax=0.8, grid=both,
xlabel=x-axis,
ylabel=y-axis 1,
y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=1,
        /tikz/.cd
    },
]
\addplot[smooth,red]%mark=x,
coordinates{
(12, 0.75)
(11, 0.749)
(10, 0.749)
(9, 0.748)
(8, 0.748)
(7, 0.746)
(6, 0.739)
(5, 0.733)
(4, 0.697)
(3, 0.674)
(2, 0.668)
}; 
\label{plot_one}
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
ytick={0.75,0.8,0.85,0.9,0.95,1.0},
legend style={at={(0.2,-0.2)}, anchor=north west},
axis y line*=right,
axis x line=none,
ymin=0.70, ymax=1,
ylabel=y-axis 2,
y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=2,
        /tikz/.cd
    },legend columns=-1
]
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_one}
\addlegendentry{y axis 1}
\addplot[smooth,blue]%,mark=*
coordinates{
(12, 0.725)
(11, 0.726)
(10, 0.73)
(9, 0.732)
(8, 0.746)
(7,0.754)
(6, 0.832)
(5, 0.828)
(4, 0.912)
(3, 0.96)
(2, 0.992)
}; 
\addlegendentry{y-axis 2}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```