# Legend entries labeled incorrectly with two

Tags: pgfplots, legend, axis

I have a graph with three plots and two y-axes. Two of the plots use the left y-axis and one uses the right y-axis. In order to get a single legend with all three plots, I am using the ideas in [this blog](https://timodenk.com/blog/latex-plot-snippets/screen-shot-2017-02-28-at-08-37-07/) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215076/63847).

However, the legend entries are appearing next to the wrong plots:

[image]

I feel like I am following the idea faithfully, but obviously I'm doing something wrong. Can you help?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[
            axis y line*=left,
            ylabel={Red and Blue},
        ]
        \addplot[red] coordinates{ (0,0) (1,1) (2,2) (3,3) }; \label{plot_red}
        \addplot[blue] coordinates{ (0,1) (1,2) (2,3) (3,4) }; \label{plot_blue}

        \end{axis}

        \begin{axis}[
            axis y line*=right,
            ylabel={Green},
        ]
        \addplot[green] coordinates{ (0,2) (1,3) (2,4) (3,5) }; \label{plot_green}

        \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_red}\addlegendentry{red line}
        \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_blue}\addlegendentry{blue line}
        \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_green}\addlegendentry{green line}

        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

By the way, if I put all three plots on the same y-axis, it works fine.

Comment: Closely related: [pgfplots: two y-axis with three plots and one legend](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198997/134144)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really only the ordering. You need to add the images before the plots (in this case).

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[
            axis y line*=left,
            ylabel={Red and Blue},
        ]
        \addplot[red] coordinates{ (0,0) (1,1) (2,2) (3,3) }; \label{plot_red}
        \addplot[blue] coordinates{ (0,1) (1,2) (2,3) (3,4) }; \label{plot_blue}

        \end{axis}

        \begin{axis}[
            axis y line*=right,
            ylabel={Green},
        ]
        \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_red}\addlegendentry{red line}
        \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_blue}\addlegendentry{blue line}
        \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_green}\addlegendentry{green line}
        \addplot[green] coordinates{ (0,2) (1,3) (2,4) (3,5) }; \label{plot_green}


        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that works! But why? What changes when you move those lines?

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 A simplified explanation might be: when `pgfplots` "sees" `\addlegendentry` then it asks itself whether or not there is a plot which it could associate the entry to, meaning it looks if there has been a plot prior to `\addlegendentry`. If that's the case, it uses the style of the plot for the entry. This  behavior is to make it most convenient to just write `\addplot... \addlegendentry...`. The price you pay for that convenience is that you need pay some attention to the ordering if you build up the legend differently.

Comment: Thank you so much, I would never have thought about this... it's actually super weird as the labels are now referenced before they are assigned, but indeed it works